# What's the purpose of aligned data for memory address

Tags: memory, cpu

I understand that physical memory is accessed by aligned chunks of 4(32-bit) or 8(64-bit) bytes.

But why do we need aligned data for memory address, lets say(in 32 bit machine):
I have a char c start at address 0(char takes one byte, then I have an integer i which start at address 1, so when I want to access the i, computer get the address of i which is 1, and then read 4 bytes from address 1 directly.

So if it works in this way, why do we need to pad 3 bytes after char c?

Answer (score 1):

As you said, "memory can be accessed by aligned chunks of 4 or 8 bytes" depending on the architecture of a computer. This means  the processor does access memory only on chunks of addresses dividable by 4 or 8 (this has pretty much to do with cost and design complexity I guess).

Let's illustrate your example :

```
struct foo {
    char c;
    int i;
};
```

Say *foo* is aligned in memory at address 0x100. If you access foo.c, you are accessing one byte only, but behind the scenes an entire word of 4 bytes has been read from memory by the CPU and the 3 next bytes in the word have been discarded.

Now if you read foo.i (wich is 4 bytes long) at memory location 0x101, the CPU will need two memory transactions. One at address 0x100 where it gets the three first bytes, and then the other one at address 0x104 to fetch the last remaining byte.

In the end, aligned data in memory saves unnecessary memory transactions.